# Prove that NAND and NOR are the only Universal Logic Gates.

Tags: boolean-algebra

I was watching this lecture: [link](https://youtu.be/V2UMDeAaZmU?t=2814)

H(x,y) is a boolean function.

He's says that H(x,y) is a Universal logic gate if and only if H(x,x) is 1 - x.

I didn't get this part.

So how to prove that NAND and NOR are the only Universal Logic Gates ?

Comment: There are infinite groups of universal logic gates are function complete, please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness . Even if we limit the size of the group to 1, we can still have [Fredkin gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredkin_gate) at airy of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H(x,x)\ne 1-x$, then constructing the single input **NOT** gate is impossible.

As for the 'iff' part, this means the only two gates left are the double input **NOT** gates, and so 'game over'!